# error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 32-bit

Tags: grub2

I got this message when I restarted my Ubuntu MATE 16.04 32-bit. How do I fix this?

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/389905/29073 ?