# How do i get the kde plasmanetbook?

Tags: installation, kde, desktop-environments, kubuntu-netbook, plasma-netbook

Recently I came across
http://www.kde.org/workspaces/plasmanetbook/
and saw several screen shots ot the plasma netbook ..
I have been using kde plasma desktop but this one looks great ..
My question is how do i get it in ubuntu????
Or are there any other destros that comes preinstalled with that plasmanetbook as my ubuntu is running very well  and i dont want to mess things up ???
Thank you

Comment: Search for it in the Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 0):

Found at, http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-install-kde-plasma-netbook.html

Basically in Software Center install **kde-plasma-netbook** :

[image: Install via the software center]

Or in Terminal ( [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) ) :

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-netbook
```

Then you should then be able to restart and switch desktops on login.