# How do I access the  Terminal?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal)

My question is in the Title.

How do I get to Terminal in Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+T and you can open the terminal.

Answer (score 8):

You have two possibilities:

1. open the Dash by clicking on the top launcher or pressing the "super"-key (Windows-icon-labelled on most keyboards) and start typing the word "terminal". When the terminal's launcher symbol appears, just click on it.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Both ways start the default gnome terminal emulator. You can install several alternative emulators from the Ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:**

> Press the **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **T** keys together

**Method 2:**

> Hit the **Windows** key and type in **terminal** (then hit the Enter Key)

**Method 3:**

> Click **Dash Home** and type in **Run** (then hit the Enter Key)

**Method 4:**

> Click **Dash Home** and type in **Terminal** (then hit the Enter Key)

**Method 5:**

> Click **Dash Home**, then **Applications** and then click **See more
>   results** near **Installed**. (It'll be in the list)

There may be more ways to access it but this is all what I know so far.

Comment: Alt + F2 -> gnome-terminal ?