# Problems with Likewise in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, likewise

I've been working with Ubuntu 12.04, it was my first time in this kind of software; I decided to move on to 13.10, but I have some problems with this...

Under 12.04, I installed Likewise without any problems, now in 13.10 I install it and seems to be allright but when I try to use it, just doesn't appear!!!

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Likewise, even re-installing Ubuntu 13.10.

I really don't know what to do.

Also when I try to modify lightdm.conf to use it for loggin in, it open in blank.

Is there another option to joining a domain?

I do really appreciate your help askubunters!!

Eduard

Comment: run it from a terminal and let us know what the output is (if there's a lot of text use pastebin.com)

Comment: Hello, Sorry but I couldn't find the way to do it... really sorry

Comment: [Open a terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/183775/how-do-i-open-a-terminal) and type `likewise-open`

Comment: Hello. I thank it was another instruction... here is the output: administrador@administrador-sistemas59:~$ likewise-open
likewise-open: no se encontró la orden
administrador@administrador-sistemas59:~$                    I installed likewise--open and likewise-open-gui Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps you need to be root try `sudo likewise-open`

Comment: also it would be wise to switch your system language to English while trouble shooting as the error codes should be much more googleable for you.

Comment: Hi there, i tried but i received the same: administrador@administrador-sistemas59:~$ sudo likewise-open
[sudo] password for administrador: 
sudo: likewise-open: orden no encontrada,

Comment: sounds like it's not installed.  Have you tried following the installation instructions here?: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen

Comment: Hey!! It Worked!! I installed it!! Thank you, I followed the instructions in the link you gave me, I was trying with an older version.

Comment: Now I'm having problems joining my domain, it shows: Unable to find ssh binary

A sshd config file was at {nowhere}, and a sshd binary file was found at {nowhere}. Exactly one config file and one binary must exist on the system in a standard location. Uninstall any unused copies of ssh.
Please see the documentation related to sshd configuration options required and re-attempt the join with "domainjoin-cli join/leave --disable ssh <domain> <username>"

Error code: ERROR_DUPLICATE_SERVICE_NAME (0x00000436) I tried using different names but anything worked, Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: ask that as a new question

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Ubuntu you are using, the install process might be slightly different.  Please try the install process listed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen