# Now that I've upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 my keyboard setting, US international with dead keys, doesn't have dead keys. How do I get them back?

Tags: upgrade, keyboard

The apostrophe key used to be the dead key.  Now when I press it all I get is apostrophe and no option for accents.

How can I restore my dead keys?

Comment: Can you [(open terminal)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/183775/how-do-i-open-a-terminal) and edit your question to include the output of this command `setxkbmap -query`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. If you go to the Dash -> text entry, remove your US international keyboard, and add it again it will work (after you've rebooted your computer)... I was looking at launchpad, but I don't know how to report it :_(

Comment: Didn't work. Still no dead keys.