# Ubuntu Terminal, what is its executable name?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, fluxbox

I would like to launch the ubuntu terminal from inside fluxbox (I don't use Unity).

However I can't manage to find the command name to launch this application ?

What's its name ?

Comment: The commands for all Ubuntu versions are in this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/183776/72216

Comment: This is not a duplicate, running a custom WM won't have the same keybindings as the major ones and the question explicitly asks for the command-line name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The GNOME terminal binary is located at `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`.

Don't mix that up with `/bin/bash`. GNOME terminal starts bash, but there's no sense in starting a bash session on its own in a GUI.

Answer (score 8):

Its name is [gnome-terminal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-terminal) :-)