# Does sudo su create a child terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, gnome-terminal, su

This is what happened when I executed `sudo su` followed by `exit`

```
$ sudo su
# exit
exit
$
```

The exit command does not close my terminal emulator.

Is it a child terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once you execute `sudo su` or `su user` a new shell is being created.

Executing `exit` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) will exit the newly create shell and will return you to your previous shell.

1. Starting point - bash shell is running on PID 25050:

   ```
   $ ps
     PID TTY          TIME CMD
   25050 pts/17   00:00:00 bash
   25200 pts/17   00:00:00 ps
   ```
2. Running `sudo su` creates a new bash process which is running on PID 25203:

   ```
   $ sudo su
   # ps
     PID TTY          TIME CMD
   25201 pts/17   00:00:00 sudo
   25202 pts/17   00:00:00 su
   25203 pts/17   00:00:00 bash
   25213 pts/17   00:00:00 ps
   # exit
   ```
3. Exiting `sudo su` and returning to the starting point - bash shell is running on PID 25050:

   ```
   $ ps
     PID TTY          TIME CMD
   25050 pts/17   00:00:00 bash
   25214 pts/17   00:00:00 ps
   $
   ```

Comment: So can that be treated as a child shell?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan - yes

Answer (score 18):

## Same terminal, different shell.

Child processes you run from a shell, including child shells, use the same terminal automatically. This is not specific to `sudo` in any way--this is generally how it works when you run any program from your shell.

[Shells and terminals are different things.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) A [**shell**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Text_.28CLI.29_shells) is what you use to run commands in a [**terminal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator). A shell can operate interactively--it gives you a prompt, you give it a command, it runs the command or shows an error about why it cannot, and the process repeats until you quit the shell. Or it can operate noninteractively, running [a script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script).

Even though your terminal is (probably!) [emulated](https://foldoc.org/terminal%20emulator), not [physical](https://foldoc.org/terminal), nonetheless [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) operating systems like Ubuntu assign [device nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) to each of your terminals, and you can check what terminal you are using with the [**`tty`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tty.1.html) command. It will usually be `/dev/pts/0`, `/dev/pts/1`, `/dev/pts/2`, [etc.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/what-are-pseudo-terminals-pty-tty), for a [terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183775/how-do-i-open-a-terminal) or [SSH connection](https://askubuntu.com/tags/ssh/info), or `/dev/tty1`, `/dev/tty2`, [etc.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277517/what-does-ctrl-alt-f12-do), for [virtual consoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). Really what `tty` does is to tell you which terminal, if any, [*input*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) is being taken from; see below for details.

```
ek@Io:~$ tty
/dev/pts/1
ek@Io:~$ bash
ek@Io:~$ tty
/dev/pts/1
ek@Io:~$ exit
exit
ek@Io:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for ek:
root@Io:/home/ek# tty
/dev/pts/1
root@Io:/home/ek# exit
exit
ek@Io:~$
```

You can see that, even though `sudo su` creates a new shell [**as Yaron very well explains**](https://askubuntu.com/a/956607/22949), the terminal you are using doesn't change.

Of course, there's another way to observe that the terminal is the same: you're still writing input the same way and in the same place, and reading output the same way and in the same place.

## A few technical details

*Most* commands you run in a shell--such as `ls`, `cp`, `mv`, `rm`, `touch`, `wc`, `du`, `df`, `ssh`, `su`, `sudo`, `sh`, `bash`, and *many* more--cause a [child process](https://foldoc.org/child%20process) to be created. This child process has your shell as its parent but it is a separate program. **By default, it is connected to the *same* terminal as your shell.**

Your shell is still running, but it waits in the background for the program to terminate (or for you [to suspend it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Basics)). When the program terminates, the shell is still running and it resumes operation, prompting you for your next command.

These are the major exceptions:

- [Shell builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) like `cd` don't create a new process at all, unless they are used in a construct that employs a [subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment) ([explained here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell)), such as [`(` `)` grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) and [pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines).
- You can tell the shell not to wait for a command to complete by [running the command *asynchronously*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists). You do this by ending the command with `&`.  (`your-command arguments... &`)
- You can use [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control) to change which command, if any, the shell waits for. With [the `disown` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Builtins), you can detach jobs from your terminal.

Though I wouldn't really consider this an exception to child processes being connected to the same terminal as their parent, note that a process you run from a shell in a terminal will *not* always be taking input from that terminal or sending output to that terminal:

- You can [redirect](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) any of the [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) with the `<`, `>`, and `>>` operators.
- You can [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) one command's [output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) to another's [input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) with `|`.

Since the `tty` command only checks which terminal its standard input is, you can "fool" it:

```
ek@Io:~$ tty
/dev/pts/1
ek@Io:~$ tty </dev/pts/0
/dev/pts/0
```

Or, less deviously:

```
ek@Io:~$ tty </dev/null  # not a terminal
not a tty
ek@Io:~$ tty <&-         # closes the input stream
not a tty
```