# Password creation

Tags: password

When I got Linux put onto my personal laptop, I wasn't asked to create a password.  Now, whenever my screen goes black, I've got to power it down and restart it in order to get back to the screen I was originally on.  How can I create a password so I don't have to do that any longer?

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: Why do you have to power it down?

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu, you almost certainly *were* asked to create a password - although you may have checked the box to not require it for logging in. If you've forgotten it, please see [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: I didn't install Ubuntu, my computer repair people did it for me at my request.

Comment: I have to power it down because after I press the power button to bring my computer back online, I don't have anything on my screen except a blank screen with the time and arrows showing.  When I power down and back up, I get my icons back.

Answer (score 0):

[Open a terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183775/how-do-i-open-a-terminal) and enter the following command:

```
whoami
```

This will return your user name.

Assuming you have root privileges, enter the following command on the terminal:

```
sudo passwd your_user_name
```

where *your_user_name* is your real user name returned by the `whoami` command. Enter a new password (two times for verification).

Use that password whenever the system prompts you.

Note: The above may not work if `sudo` prompts for your current password which you do not know.

Comment: `passwd` should NOT be run with `sudo` - `passwd` uses `setuid` to gain file access. `sudo passwd` changes `root`'s password.

Comment: Actually this was a shortcut for `sudo -i` and then `passwd your_user_name`. If the first command (`sudo -i`) prompts for current user's password then this method will not work, since the current password is not known.