# How can I open Java's Control Panel?

Tags: java, security, settings

How can I open Java's Control Panel to change the security settings?

Comment: What Java Control Panel?

Comment: Dash -> search "java" -> open java control panel -> open tab "security". It's that easy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you've manually installed Oracle Java it doesn't show up in the Dash (as far as I know).

1. Open a terminal
2. Execute the following command:

   ```
   /usr/bin/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/ControlPanel
   ```

   *Replace `/usr/bin/jdk1.8.0_05` by the path of your Java installation.*

Answer (score 17):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and start

```
ControlPanel
```

Just a few moments later the Java Control Panel appeared.  I haven't checked yet, but it may be necessary to

```
sudo ControlPanel
```

to save your changes.

Comment: Pity the other answer was already accepted as this one is much more clean and succinct.

Comment: Shouldn't `sudo -H` be used here? I've been told running a GUI application as root can cause trouble.

Answer (score 7):

1. [Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/174443/75166)
2. Execute the command: `jcontrol`

Answer (score 4):

Hit the super key, search for "java" and it will show, amongst others, "java plugin control panel" if it is installed that is.

[image]

Comment: Medium level is now removed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Path you saved Java.

Type

```
cd jre/bin/
sh ControlPanel
```

Answer (score 0):

as of java9... (Oct 2017)

This assumes you have installed java9 yourself (since the webupd8 PPA method is currently broken).  After repeated purging of all things java-related (especially the default-installed java), I've not taken the time to fix the "update alternatives" infrastructure, so that particular link to jcontrol is borked (that is, the answer above -- "just type jcontrol in a terminal window" -- does not work).

This also assumes you have a working java installation (java -version returns something).

```
 # ls -al `which java`
```

You'll get something back like this:

```
  lrwxrwxrwx ... /usr/bin/java -> /usr/java/default/bin/java
```

So your command will be:

```
 # /usr/java/default/bin/jcontrol
```

Now, you can fix the alternatives link (the quick-and-dirty way), so you *can* just type jcontrol and have it work. I do recommend you use the update-alternatives structures (be sure you know what you are doing before taking these steps.  I suggest using ls -al to check the links).  This is done as root.  You can put sudo in front of the commands if you feel better about doing that.

```
# ln -s -f /usr/java/default/bin/jcontrol /etc/alternatives/jcontrol
# ln -s -f /etc/alternatives/jcontrol /usr/bin/jcontrol
```