# g77-3.4 installed from Hardy repositories but

Tags: 12.04

I need g77-3.4 and have installed it from hardy repositories on Ubuntu 12.04 but to compile a program after make command it returns g77: command not found
this procedure have no problem on Ubuntu 9.01, 10.10. is there any way to link "g77" to its proper location?

Answer (score 1):

Install `cook` from the standard repository. You don't need to install packages from hardy repository.

[Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it) and execute this command below:

```
sudo apt-get install cook
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you i try it. but what does "cook" do?

Comment: I guess it does not work because the program i am compiling is written by fortran 77 and needs g77-3.4 to compile the problem is that ubuntu 12.04 does not recognize g77-3.4 compiler

Comment: Did you tried this?