# how does one get to terminal mode in later versions of ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity’s keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)
>   [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it)

In earlier versions of ubuntu, I could install wireless cards using terminal and ndiswrapper. In later versions I don't see an obvious way to get to the terminal mode.

Comment: There's a terminal application installed by default in every regular Ubuntu version, including recent versions. What exactly makes you think there's no terminal application installed? What have you tried?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts ;) (Ctrl-Alt-T - Launch a terminal window.)

Comment: you can also try Ctrl-Alt-F1.  Ctrl-Alt-F7 to return to Unity

Answer (score 2):

If by "terminal mode" you mean the TTY, it's the same as older versions of Ubuntu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. You can replace 1 by any number between 1 and 6. The 7 will bring you back to graphic desktop. TTY is a complete independent session without graphical interface, so you'll need to log in first.

If you just want to open a terminal window, just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.