# How to eject a CD/DVD from the command line

Tags: command-line, dvd, eject

I've just right clicked on the DVD icon in the Unity Launcher in order to eject it, but instead of hitting the 'Eject' button, I missed and hit the 'Unlock from Launchpad' option instead.

How do I go about ejecting the disk from the drive now that the Launcher option is missing?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In order to eject a disk from the drive, whether it's a CD or a DVD, [open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it) and simply execute the `eject` command.

Comment: Does the icon come back next time you insert a disc?

Comment: The icon does not actually come back for that particular disk. A similar one will appear, at a lower resolution and without the eject option, and the full one will appear when you insert a new disk. I'm not sure how to undo this - I'm still looking into that.

Comment: I think you need too add the device after the eject command, like eject /dev/sr0  ---
It seems the default symlink /dev/dvd is not created anymore by default, and "eject" only works for /dev/dvd when entered without parameters

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 16.04 via remote shell (SSH). It requires `sudo`.

Comment: `eject` worked for me then got stopped working, with the following error: "eject: /dev/cdrom: not found mountpoint or device with the given name".  After executing `eject /dev/sr0` I could again use `eject`, `eject -T` etc.

Comment: THIS even works for an Apple Superdrive, that wont eject the disc under MacOS.

Answer (score 23):

To open the CD drive / eject the CD:

- Open Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and type `eject`
- To close the tray, type `eject -t`
- And to toggle (if open, close and if closed, open) type `eject -T`

All these commands can be typed into the run dialogue (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)

For more options, type `eject -h` into Terminal.

Answer (score 11):

## Opening the Tray

Commands:

- open tray: `eject`
- close tray: `eject -t`

### Easy Function for .bashrc

`alias opentray='eject'`

A few issues arise when ejecting drives. Sometimes they don't want to eject, because they are mounted etc. You can override this with `eject -l /media/mountpoint` or (`/mnt/mountpoint`). I wrote a function that can be called by simply typing `opentray` on your command line.

### Notice

This works only if

- you **setup a permanent mount** point for your drive `/dev/sr0` (same thing as `/dev/cdrom`, which is just symbolically linked to `/dev/sr0`)
- your **mount point is automatically created** when you insert a disk into the drive. *(This can be ignored if you remove/comment out all lines where rm -r "${mountdir}" exists that way the mount point will never be removed automatically)*
- Must **run as root** unless you changed the permissions manually of mounting functions (I have never tried this)

---

```
function opentray ()
{
    mountdir="/media/DVD"
    if [ -d "${mountdir}" ] # If directory ${mountdir} exists
    then
        if [ $(mount | grep -c "${mountdir}") = 1 ] # If drive is mounted, then
        then
            echo "/dev/sr0 is now mounted to ${mountdir}. I'll try to unmount it first and eject/open the tray."
            umount -l "${mountdir}"
            rm -r "${mountdir}"
            sysctl -w dev.cdrom.autoclose=0 # Ensure drive doesn't auto pull tray back in.  
            eject
            exit
        else
            echo "/dev/sr0 is not mounted. Opening the tray should be easy. Ejecting/opening now."
            rm -r "${mountdir}"
            sysctl -w dev.cdrom.autoclose=0 # Ensure drive doesn't auto pull tray back in.  
            eject
            exit
        fi
    else
        echo 'The directory "${mountdir}" does not exist. Ejecting/opening the tray.'
        sysctl -w dev.cdrom.autoclose=0 # Ensure drive doesn't auto pull tray back in.
        eject
        exit
    fi
}
```

---

## Closing the Tray

For completeness, you can add this alias to your `.bashrc` ( or `.bash_aliases` file) to pull the tray back in from the command line. You do not need to be root.

```
alias closetray='eject -t'
```

Answer (score 2):

The man page for eject on Ubuntu contains no force options (either -F or --force).

You may eject a "busy" (in use) DVD:

```
eject -m
```

This worked for me to replace a defective dvd with a freshly burned one to continue an installation.

Answer (score 2):

The eject command might fail if it does not recognize your external cdrom drive. In that case, you will have to identify the `/dev` device manually and run the explicit command. A good candidate if you have an external USB drive is

`eject /dev/sr0`

Answer (score 1):

In the application "Terminal" either enter:

- `eject`
- `eject --force`

Comment: `eject --force` → `eject: unrecognized option '--force'`

Comment: For older kernels: `eject -F`

Comment: The `--force` doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04, but `eject -v /dev/sr0` does give usefull information. (or `eject -h`)