# is there a way to set handbrake to eject the tray after ripping a dvd?

Tags: dvd, eject, handbrake

i looked into the settings of handbrake
but found nothing to make handbrake eject the
dvd tray after succesfull ripping a dvd.
i dont really know if it is possible
but this is linux and they always find
ways to do things, even if its not
implemented into an application.
so i was wondering if there is any way
to make handbrake eject after a succesful
rip. i dont want/cant use another program
for dvd ripping also, handbrake is the
only one i found working on my system
to rip copyprotected dvds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HandBrake does not support and is [not going to support ejecting optical disks](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/issues/1624#issuecomment-428288231).

So I can imagine two “Linux”<sup>1</sup> ways to achieve this:

1. Download HandBrake source, add the feature and [build HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/developer/install-dependencies-ubuntu.html) yourself.
2. Use [HandBrake from the command line](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/cli-options.html) and add the [`eject` command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226638/how-to-eject-a-cd-dvd-from-the-command-line) when HandBrake [finishes successfully](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists). Pseudocode:

   ```
   handbrake <parameters> && eject
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup> Both the mentioned ways are also achievable on non-Linux OSes like macOS or Windows.