# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS won't play DVD's

Tags: rhythmbox, dvd, drive

I am a bit of a novice at this so please keep your answers as simple as possible.I have a Z91F laptop onto which I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I also had to replace the old cd drive with a reconditioned DVD multi recorder RW drive. I am able to play music CD's ok through Rhythmbox but when a dvd is inserted a few clicks are heard followed by a short spin followed by more clicks and searching of the dvd.The dvd then stops.No window opens up at all.I have read some of the comments already made about installing `sudo apt-get install libdvdread4` and then `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install -css.sh` as a possible solution to my problem. But how do I actually do this?

Comment: Terminal? http://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it

Answer (score 0):

Just type these commands in the terminal window. After you type these commands you have to type your password because the command sudo says you have temporary root access rights.

Comment: where is the command?