# How Can I Install Adobe Air on 12.04 64-bit?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, adobe-air

Any solution is not do anything on my machine.
I downloaded air
Installed 32 bit packages but always said "permission denied"

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-adobe-flash-reader-air-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

### For 64bit

In terminal ([What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it)) copy and paste each command then hit enter one command at a time. `sudo` commands will ask for a password, type your password and hit enter(there will be no visual indication of typing a password)- if you password does not work: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

3. `wget http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/latest/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`
4. `sudo chmod +x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`
5. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0`
6. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0`
7. `sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`

Answer (score 1):

With adobe air u need to use **Adobe Air version 2.6** (only one I were able to run on 64 bit 12.04)
since adobe stuck support for Linux. Never version most likely wont work at all.

Second issue with adobe air is  that it mostly search for needed libraries on wrong place, however  this  post [here](http://jeffhendricks.net/?p=68m)!, helped me to instal Adobe Air.

Comment: I have tried all guys same all!
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7CTLz.png

Comment: also this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wb1z0.png

Comment: I'm unsure now. did you manage to install it or not?