# how to use the terminal with linux 13.10?

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, command-line, execute-command

I would like to know how can I use the terminal? The functionality of commands. I don't know how can I use the terminal for download movies or software.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you insist on terminal? You can easily download movies or software using web browser or Software Center.

Comment: ok but if I use torrents for movies I'll get some virus

Comment: Well, torrents aren't always legal, so I wouldn't stay away from them just because of viruses. However, this is similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it like xangua said. Marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

From a combination of your post and subsequent comment I think there is some misunderstanding of what the terminal is/does. The terminal is a non-graphical interface for you to communicate with your computer. This gives you a great deal of control over your PC as no program has a button for every terminal command (and if one did it would be so full of buttons it would be impossible to use!)

Graphical programs, take your inputs, and essentially run terminal-like commands. This means that downloading a file from the terminal is not intrinsically "safer" than downloaded the same file from your browser. The important issue is the content of the file that you have downloaded. It is also arguable that the terminal is less safe in the hands of a confused user as it is much easier to "accidentally" give a downloaded file root (administrator) permissions by just copying commands you have seen online (in this case `sudo`).

If you want to download movies "safely" the only real option is a reliable (and therefore probably legal) source (but, not that all legal sources a malware free!!).

For software. Illegal software is again less likely to be safe (also not legal to download!). You can download free legal packages in the terminal from ubuntu's repositories. For this you need the name and run:

```
sudo apt-get install PACKAGENAME
```

But if you are just browsing you can use the Ubuntu software centre. This is equally "safe". There is a lot to choose from.