# Adobe flash player privacy settings

Tags: flash

Concerned with my privacy and the abuse that today every single company of jerks exert upon it I decided to switch from win 7 to Ubuntu but being a newbie (ubuntu is so much different!) I can't find where are settings.sol and mms.cfg stored. In windows the first is in `users/app data/roaming/macromed/sys` and the second one (64 bit) in `windows/syswow64/macromed/flash`. I read that setting the mms.cfg file correctly can prevent flash based websites from spying on you so I wanna set that right in ubuntu. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To find these files, you can use these commands in a [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it):

```
locate settings.sol
locate mms.cfg
```

`settings.sol` is located at (where `$USER` is your username)

```
/home/$USER/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/settings.sol
```

`mms.cfg` seems not to exist...

Answer (score 1):

While the contents of `mms.cfg` depend on your needs, you may create such a file in `/etc/adobe` or in `~/.adobe` if it doesn't already exist.

Useful links include:

- https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer (with a sample `mms.cfg`)

and

- http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/www-plugins/adobe-flash/files/mms.cfg which is extensively commented.

Manipulating `settings.sol` seems more complicated but it is discussed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82802/15760

You could also look at [Getting Rid of Nasty Adobe Flash Cookies the Cool Linux Way](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6709/1) for advice offered in 2009.

On my system, I see this:

```
[11:15 AM] ~ $ locate settings.sol
/home/vasa1/.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/CFJHX928/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/settings.sol
/home/vasa1/.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/CFJHX928/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/#s.ytimg.com/settings.sol
/home/vasa1/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/settings.sol
/home/vasa1/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/#s.ytimg.com/settings.sol
[11:16 AM] ~ $
```

Note that running the `file` command on these files shows that they are `data`. But part two of [Carla Schroder's link](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6709/2) suggests that you can get rid of them interactively using:

```
find -iname '*.sol' -ok rm "{}" \;
```

I tried that command and it still works in 2014; `find` may take a little while before you see anything on your terminal screen.