# How do I get YouTube to work?

Tags: flash, youtube

I just downloaded Ubuntu. But when I go to YouTube the videos play horribly and I get a window saying the plug in is needed but then when I try to add it it says it can't find a suitable plug in. I have tried to download flash player and Lightstream and I have no idea what is going on with either one. I keep launching them over and over and nothing works. I have no idea what to do, can someone help?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Can you be more clear. I have no idea what pepper is, what a terminal is, what any of these terms mean. Can you tell me how to get my YouTubes working on Ubuntu? I need to have Youtube working or this operating system is of no use to me.

Comment: visit youtube.com/html5 and enable it

Comment: You can install Flash player as described in dobey's linked question, and then you should be able to play videos on youtube. You can use also use the HTML5 player by enabling it here: http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer:  Load google Chrome - adobe stopped supporting Flash Player for Linux about a year ago.

Comment: I just did load google Chrone and that does not work either. The YouTube videos will barely play. Any suggestions?

Comment: Easier answer - use normal flash plugin

Comment: I wish!  The current (very old) flash plugin for Linux is not reading many sites for me.

Comment: Normal flash plug in works but of course one has to go back to Windows 7 for it to function.

Comment: ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my new Linux Mint and got an easy solution.

Open Terminal and type in :

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

If you are not comfortable with terminals follow this GUI tutorial by Ubuntu :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what is a TERMINAL ?  Is that like the place I go to wait for an airplane? Seriously I have no idea what you're talking about :)

Comment: Okay, I went to the wiki.ubuntu.com area and unfortunately that is not functional. It would not complete that vital step so I could choose the plug in.  Took about a half hour too. This is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: Okay, since the ubuntu tutorial didn't function can someone possibly tell me how to Open a Terminal?  If it's not hugely complicated I'd like to do that.

Comment: Okay!  I figured out how to get there via a Terminal. So I put the "pepperflashplugin-nonfree" term in there and then had to type my password and now rows of weird numbers went all up and down my screen.  I have no idea what this means. Does this mean YouTube works now. I'll be surprised!!

Comment: Okay, just as I thought!  I went onto the Internet tried to play a video and the window still came up and said that I DON'T have an suitable plug in!  So what did I get this Pepper plug in for then ?

Comment: OH THIS IS NICE. MY MUSIC DOESN'T PLAY RIGHT EITHER.  I am totally done with this system. Good bye!

Comment: You sound to me _really_crazy_. You're not made for linux operating systems switch back to windows. It's made specially for you. :D

Comment: When I run this in the terminal:`sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install`, I get this output: 

`2014-07-26 01:56:02 (2,47 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/pepperflashplugin-nonfree.BqGj40yYUE/google-chrome-stable_36.0.1985.125-1_amd64.deb’ saved [48386260/48386260]`

and after restarting Chromium, Flash is still not detected. I really need help! Can someone help me? Should I install that .deb file found in the /tmp directory?

Comment: Running `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status` prints the following lines in the terminal:
```Flash Player version installed on this system  : 14.0.0.145
Flash Player version available on upstream site: 14.0.0.145``` But I still don't have Flash in Chromium.

Comment: And it is very strange that I have this entry in chrome://plugins : http://i861.photobucket.com/albums/ab180/silviubogan/Screenshotfrom2014-07-26022752.png

Answer (score 0):

#### Installing Flash Player

Open terminal by 'CTRL+ALT+T'

close firefox
copy & past this 'line by line'

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

'suggestions : 1 - try to learn ubuntu desktop there's so many video tutorials,2 - learn the command line too'
you can download & watch youtube videos by installing youtube-dl

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

#### usage in terminal

```
youtube-dl "youtube video link or the video id"
```

you can also download a youtube video playlist

```
youtube-dl -cit "the youtube playlist link"
```

#### more info

```
youtube-dl --help
```

it gonna auto download in the /home folder
you can download them in Download dir by getting into the Download dir

```
cd Download
```

then 
the

```
youtube-dl -command "video link"
```