# Problem Opening Terminal

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, gnome-terminal

Ubuntu is a totally new system for me, and I installed it on virtual box. Today when I tried to open terminal in Ubuntu, it just can't open it. Yesterday I could use the terminal normally, and I changed nothing. The terminal does have a response when I click it, but no window shows up. What's wrong with it, and what should I do?

Comment: The terminal is command line based. You type stuff in and it gets executed. You can get [more out of it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it) if you just mess around(practicing commands, etc).

Comment: Ubuntu comes with two terminals by default: `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`. Open the Dash and search for `xterm`. Open it and  try to reinstall `gnome-terminal` as `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal` . xterm by default has very very small font, so you will have to change it via Ctrl_Left button + Right_Click. Let me know if that helps

Comment: You can also try calling `gnome-terminal` from `xterm` specifically. It should show diagnostic messages in command line. So from `xterm` type `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` and hit enter. Let us know what happens

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and type `gnome-terminal` into the resulting window. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and see if the terminal appears.

Comment: The user uses Virtual Box, so it has to be left Alt button, not just any Alt.