# How to get dual boot (Ubuntu/Windows) option enabled?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My first disk has windows and second disk (not partition) has Ubuntu.

But **the first disk was removed during ubuntu installation** and **plugged back after installation**.

Now my system boots with only one OS depending on the disk with higher priority in the boot list.

One of the attached question talks about boot repair or about reinstalling grub-efi. Which is not the case here. My system boots perfectly but based on the drive selected.

The other attached question is valid with the given assumptions being true, which are false in my case.

Is there any way to get OS selection list at boot time?

Comment: have you tried updating grub after logging on to Ubuntu?

Comment: How is the external drive connected? USB, SATA, etc

Comment: @Stiffy2000 which external drive? Both drives are SSD SATA and both are internal.

Comment: @tod good, its solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the following should be sufficient:

1. Boot Ubuntu with both drives installed.
2. [Open Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it) and issue the command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Enter your password and check it detects Windows apart from Ubuntu itself.
4. You can reboot and choose Windows in the GRUB menu.

However, this might not work if you installed both systems in a different mode (BIOS or UEFI). Anyway, a boot menu provided by the firmware can do the same work as the GRUB menu would.

Comment: Yeah, just **sudo update-grub** did the job. It prompted for password and detected windows. On reboot it showed both OS. P.S. my 2nd disk with Ubuntu on it, is on higher priority in the boot list.

Comment: Btw, I am just wondering if I want to undo it, what would be the command/procedure? 

Because, if i remove either of the OS in future, I would not be interested to see this boot list.

Comment: @tod If you removed the Windows drive, you could just remove its drive (or format it, for example) and run `update-grub` again. It discovers the change and applies it to GRUB. If you removed the Ubuntu drive, nothing would have to be done since you haven’t made any changes to the Windows bootloader.