# E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run dpkg, configure a' to correct the problem

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, downloads

I am getting the error below while downloading the apps from ubuntu software center.

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run dpkg, configure a' to correct the problem.
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

[Open up a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it) and run the said command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message said, running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` will solve the problem.
However, I believe running `sudo apt install -f` would be better.
I don't have a Ubuntu system available right now, so I can't .

1. Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal
2. Type the command you choose. Fix problem using apt or dpkg by using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt install -f`
3. After you run one, go back to make sure software is installing. If it is, type `exit` of click the red <kbd>X</kbd> to close the terminal. If not, run the other command.