# How can I install Laidout in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

How can I install [Laidout](http://laidout.org), the desktop publishing software, in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to install Laidout in Ubuntu 16.04 ([Source](http://laidout.org/index.html#download))

If you are unaware of what the terminal is, please see this question first:
[What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it)

#### 1. Install dependencies

Open up the terminal and type this command to install Laidout dependencies.

```
sudo apt install g++ pkg-config libpng-dev libgegl-dev libreadline-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxi-dev libxft-dev libcups2-dev libimlib2-dev libfontconfig-dev libfreetype6-dev libssl-dev xutils-dev libcairo2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libsqlite3-dev libgraphicsmagick++1-dev zlib1g-dev mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libftgl-dev
```

#### 2. Download and extract Laidout

[Download Laidout from Github](https://github.com/Laidout/laidout/releases/download/0.097/laidout-0.097.tar.bz2) as a compressed file and save it in your desktop.
Using your terminal go to your desktop, extract it there and then enter into the Laidout folder. Run these commands one at a time.

```
cd ~/Desktop
tar xvfj laidout-0.097.tar.bz2
cd laidout-0.097/
```

#### 3. Install Laidout

Make sure you are in the Laidout folder in the terminal and then run these commands one at a time:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
sudo make
sudo make install
```

#### 4. Open Laidout

If the above steps produce no error, we can now open Laidout by typing in the terminal:

```
laidout
```

This should open a Laidout window where you can create new documents or open existing ones. The screenshot below I have opened one of the example files, monkey.doc

[image: Laidout window]

#### 5. Uninstall

If somehow you want to uninstall Laidout from your system, follow these steps.
Enter into your extracted Laidout folder in your desktop, then run this terminal command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```