# Why "Failed to download repository information" when I try to install Flash?

Tags: installation, package-management, flash

I want to install Flash Player.

But it only shows: `Failed to download repository information`.

How can I install Adobe Flash Player?

```
anonymous@anonymous-945GCM-S2L:~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer  
[sudo] password for anonymous:   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: nor terminal run any command like "sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installation

Comment: If you have to add anything to your question please do it by editing the question

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and run:

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Downloads and Installs the Adobe Flash Player plugin. The Adobe Flash Player
plugin supports playing of media and other dynamic content online.

The Adobe Flash Player plugin will work with a range of web-browsers including,
limited to:

Firefox, Chromium, SeaMonkey, Iceweasel, Iceape, Galeon, Epiphany, Konqueror.

WARNING: Installing this Ubuntu package causes the Adobe Flash Player plugin to
be downloaded from the Adobe web site. The distribution license of the
Adobe Flash Player plugin is available at www.adobe.com. Installing this
Ubuntu package implies that you have accepted the terms of that license.

Comment: this is not work  , it show the message anonymous@anonymous-945GCM-S2L:~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer  
[sudo] password for anonymous:   
**Reading package lists... Done**  
**Building dependency tree**         
**Reading state information... Done**  
**E: Unable to locate package flashplugin-installer**  @dll file missing

Answer (score 2):

When you think you're right about the name of a package, but you get a `Unable to locate package ...` error, you should make sure you have the *software source* (also called a *repository*) enabled that provides the package.

For packages provided in official Ubuntu software sources, you can use [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Searching for `flashplugin-installer` [reveals](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=flashplugin-installer&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) that it is in the [multiverse repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#What_are_Repositories.3F).

That makes sense; this repository is for "software that is not free" ([Repositories/Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)). Adobe Flash Player is non-free (i.e., proprietary) software.

So, enable the multiverse repository component:

- [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

Then you can install `flashplugin-installer` by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Alternatively, you can just use the [Software Center](http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/features/find-more-apps) to install [flashplugin-installer [image: Install flashplugin-installer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flashplugin-installer); it will figure out what repository is needed and let you enable it.

#### However, I recommend installing it via a different package altogether.

`flashplugin-installer` works, but it has a couple of shortcomings:

- It does not directly provide the Flash Plugin; instead, it provides scripts that download them.
- It [provides the 32-bit version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49298/whats-the-difference-between-flashplugin-installer-and-adobe-flashplugin/49312#49312) of Adobe Flash on both 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu systems.

There is another package that provides Adobe Flash directly and in either 32-bit or 64-bit architecture: [adobe-flashplugin [image: Install adobe-flashplugin]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/adobe-flashplugin).

You can install it in the Software Center, or you can manually enable the [Partner repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Canonical_Partner_Repositories) (the software source that provides it) and then install it manually.

To enable the Partner repository:

- [How do I enable the "partner" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository)

To install `adobe-flashplugin` from the command line, once Partner is enabled:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

**Please note that you should not have *both* `flashplugin-installer`/`flashplugin-nonfree` and `adobe-flashplugin` installed at the same time; if you managed to get both installed, they can conflict.**