# There isn’t a software package called `adobe-flashplugin` in your current software sources

Tags: firefox, flash

I am trying to install the `adobe-flashplugin` on Ubuntu 14.04.
On Adobe's site I choose the "APT for Ubuntu 10.04+" option.
It opens Ubuntu software Center, but it tells me

```
There isn’t a software package called “adobe-flashplugin” in your current software sources
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to install Flash, you can install it using the command -

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Alternatively, to install Adobe flash from canonical partner repository -

`Software & Updates` -> Tab 'Other Software' -> Tick 'Canonical Partners'

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

Comment: Crafty edit there ;)

Comment: Was on the app and didn't see your answer. I'll upvote it :-)

Comment: No worries, our answers AND edits were less than a minute apart.

Answer (score 2):

Its available in the partner repository.

If you goto System Settings > Software & Updates, then to the "Other Software" tab check  the "Canonical Partners" checkbox.
You should get prompted for a password and then to reload.

After this you will be able to load adobe-flashplugin using the method in your question.

You can also install flash (exactly the same as both download flash from Adobe's website), using flashplugin-installer, also available from the software centre.