# package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate . How can i solve this error?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, flash

I'm trying to install a newest version of flash player on my laptop, I'm running ubuntu 14.04.5 (by flashdrive, not using a dual boot). I was reading other questions about this topic but I keep getting this error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or 
is only available from another source

E: package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You need to enable the Partners repository first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get latest Flash player on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524279/get-latest-flash-player-on-ubuntu) and [There isn’t a software package called `adobe-flashplugin` in your current software sources](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562038/there-isn-t-a-software-package-called-adobe-flashplugin-in-your-current-softwa)

Comment: @CelticWarrior  I've already checked every option in software&updates windows

Comment: You need to enable the Partners repository first: Software & Updates > **Other software**.

Comment: Searching that path I'm finding only two options : http://ppa.launchpad/wbupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main  http://ppa.launchpad/wbupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main (Source Code)

Comment: `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner" >>/etc/apt/sources.list'`