# Youtube videos do not play in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: youtube

Youtube videos do not play. Instead, the following messages appear: "This plugin is vulnerable and should be updated", "Activate Adobe Flash", "Check for updates."
Since my version is 14.04LTS, the Adobe Flash Player cannot be installed. What should I do for playing Youtube videos. The browser I use is Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play the Youtube videos in Firefox now, just press the *"Activate Adobe Flash"* button.

Or use HTML5 for Youtube, there should be a *"Request the HTML5 player"* button on https://www.youtube.com/html5

I have the same problem with Firefox v.33 & 35 (latest for [trusty & trusty-updates is v.35](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/firefox)). I've read about it a few other places (don't have the links now), I think it's a bug; I couldn't find any fix or workaround for it, aside from just using Flash as a click-to-play plugin, which is fine with me.

Firefox is up to date, and the flash plugin is up to date:

- going to the Mozilla's ["Plugin Check & Updates"](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_campaign=plugincheck-update) (the *"Check for updates..."* link on any flash video) says Shockwave Flash is Up to Date
- clicking the Action button *"Up to Date"* goes to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ which also says the latest version (last version for Linux actually) is 11.2.202.442
- the latest Ubuntu trusty package of [flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.442ubuntu0.14.04.1)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/flashplugin-installer) is the same 11.2.202.442

Chrome/Chromium does have it's own built-in flash player (a Pepper Plugin API?), and I saw an [article on WebUpd8.org about a Firefox plugin](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/fresh-player-plugin-sees-new-release.html) available on the WebUpd8 PPA that should let you use the newer Pepper flash player in Firefox. See [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576562/apt-way-to-get-adobe-flash-player-latest-version-for-linux-not-working/576569#576569) (or the WebUpd8 article) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Get Google Chrome, it comes with Flash already installed.