# Latest version of Flash Player

Tags: firefox, flash

Several minutes ago I downloaded the latest version of Flash Player from the Adobe website and installed it. When I open a page with flash content, like Youtube, Firefox still pops up a message that I have an older version of Flash that is not supported. What to do?

Comment: which is the flash version installed ?

Comment: It says: 11.2.202.481ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: You have the latest version.  Adobe will no longer have updates for flash player under Linux.  Form Adobe's website: NOTE: Adobe Flash Player 11.2 will be the last version to target Linux as a supported platform. Adobe will continue to provide security backports to Flash Player 11.2 for Linux.

Comment: As a workaround I installed the Fresh Player Plugin, works like a charm. http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-fresh-player-plugin-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adobe Flash Plugin is vulnerable/outdated in 14.04 but there is no update in Firefox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562035/adobe-flash-plugin-is-vulnerable-outdated-in-14-04-but-there-is-no-update-in-fir)

Answer (score 2):

Install Pepper Flash Plugin instead of Adobe Flash

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Comment: After doing this it looks like Firefox continues to use the Adobe Flash plugin. How do I get Firefox to use the new pepper flash plugin?

Answer (score 0):

you mention using firefox. to my knowledge, pepperflash is a plugin designed for use in chrome and chromium browsers, not firefox. 
there are those who say "freshplayer" is a wrapper to allow pepperflash to be used, but i have not tested it...
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/fresh-player-plugin-pepper-flash.html
good luck