# How to complete installation of flash plugin?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, flash

I recently received an upgrade for the flash plugin through the package manager.
I've installed it. Flash then requires a reboot and running a post installation step. I've been having trouble with this last step.

Whenever I login I can see an item in my notification bar that asks to install other packages to make flash work. This is what comes out when clicking it:

[image: Image of request to install packages for flash plugin]

I press <kbd>OK</kbd> and then I insert my password to run the installation and it fails:

[image: A dialog stating that an error occurred.]

If I try to click on <kbd>Details>></kbd> nothing happens.

Since the first time that this thing happened I get warnings when using flash on firefox (it says that the plugin is obsolete or something like that).

How can I fix this? Is there a way to run the above step from the command line and check what's going on and the cause of the error?

---

This is **not** a duplicate of: [Adobe Flash Plugin is vulnerable/outdated in 14.04 but there is no update in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562035/adobe-flash-plugin-is-vulnerable-outdated-in-14-04-but-there-is-no-update-in-fir)

In that question:

- The problem is **not** due to an update release (i.e. the user does have installed the latest plugin; not so for me)
- The problem is caused by a wrong version comparison

In my case I **do not** have installed the latest version, and this process fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adobe Flash Plugin is vulnerable/outdated in 14.04 but there is no update in Firefox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562035/adobe-flash-plugin-is-vulnerable-outdated-in-14-04-but-there-is-no-update-in-fir)

Comment: @DJCrashdummy This is **not** a duplicate. The question you link is about an error in the version number. My issue is that there **is** an updated version, I installed it but the final step of the installation is unable to complete successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reinstalling it like this: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`.

PS: You may also consider ditching flash in view of the [recent discoveries](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/07/once-again-adobe-releases-emergency-flash-patch-for-hacking-team-0-days/).

Comment: I just started getting this exact problem a few days ago in xenial (after things working fine for a long time). I have `adobe-flashplugin` installed - not `flashplugin-installer`. When I selected that for installation, it said it was going to remove the one I have installed. I want to get this resolved, but also get the 23 version when it comes out. What's the best way to proceed?