# I'm unable to play song from musicindiaonline.com in 64bit ver

Tags: firefox, music, codecs

I have 64bit version of Ubuntu. I'm unable to play songs from the site [musicindiaonline.com](http://musicindiaonline.com). One solution is to install real player but real player works only on 32bit. What is the solution to this. Some plugins for real player, mplayer etc and all are installed in firefox but of no use. Its the latest version 11.04

Comment: Can you verify whether the site works for you now...? I believe it should.

Answer (score 1):

MusicIndiaOnline appears to be using Flash as its playback backend now, which works fine on Ubuntu. [Install Adobe Flash](https://askubuntu.com/q/11/24694) and you should be able to listen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in mostly Bollywood songs, I recommend [grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/).

If not, you can use the Nvuola Player to play from desktop, it supports Google music, Grooveshark, etc.

Comment: also install adobeflash-plugin which provides a GTK configuration app in dash ...

very usefull cause for some reason facebook doesnt detect camera, u have to go to flash settings and manually enter facebook.com and allow it.

also advisable to quit firefox till installation of flash completes