# How does one go about installing flash 11 (64bit)?

Tags: 64-bit, flash

How does someone install the new beta version of flash 11?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

Comment: For the stable version of Flash 11 64bit, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player/78498#78498 to get it working properly on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown here http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/adobe-releases-flash-player-11-beta.html you can use the following commands:

> sudo mkdir /usr/lib/kde4
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sevenmachines/flash
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install flashplugin64-installer

You can also follow the manual installation as shown in the link above

Comment: you shouldn't need to be installing KDE4 in order to make it work.  The user wasnt specific about which version of Ubuntu is needed.  As such, /usr/lib/kde4 isnt a needed folder.

Comment: The tar provided by adobe includes kde files as well and sevenmachines flash-installer gives error if directory is not made.

Comment: so you are saying that the installer is dependent on KDE libraries?

Comment: The article above mentioned that " ..because the latest Flash comes with some KDE libraries so you need to create that folder to avoid an error on non-KDE systems"

It didn't create any performance issue on my gnome system though, if that's what you are worried about

Answer (score 3):

Install [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) and run the extension Wizard. Flash-Aid allows to install Flash 64bit from Adobe Labs (32bit from repos and Chrome too), it removes conflicting plugins and apply performance tweaks. Additionally, it has a plugin update checker, so you can be notified about new beta versions.

Comment: Definitely the safest and easiest way. The removing of conflicts helps greatly.

Comment: It got safer now (v 2.2.0), with SSL and plugin hash check :-)

Comment: @ lovinglinux: how do you check which version of flash your using since installing the beta version from adobe labs doesn't show up in any package manager?

Comment: Type *about:plugins* in the address bar of Firefox, Chrome or Opera. you can also configure Firefox to show the full path, by changing the preference *plugin.expose_full_path* in *about:config*

Answer (score 0):

The sevenmachine ppa is the best bet to keep up-to-date with flash 64 bit. Otherwise download the tar archive for linux from [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplatformruntimes/flashplayer11/flashplayer11_b1_install_lin_64_071311.tar.gz).

extract it and save the libflashplayer.so file on mozilla plugin path. Either locally or on `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugin`. You can copy the files mentioned inside the tar on respective places .i.e inside /usr folder avoiding the kde ones if you don't use kde