# Flash in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: firefox, 11.10, google-chrome, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed, I have the flashplugin:i386 installed, however both Google Chrome and Firefox are telling me that flash is not installed.

The flash configuration utility is there, so I know that it is installed, it's just not showing up.

How can I fix this?

```
hailwood@ubuntu:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep flash
adobe-flash-properties-gtk:i386     install
adobe-flashplugin:i386              install
flashplugin-downloader:i386         install
```

Comment: Flash is available in the Software Center:

- http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player