# France24 EN streaming in Firefox

Tags: firefox, streaming

I'm not able to stream France24 EN in Firefox (the stream doesn't start...)

http://www.france24.com/en/aef_player_popup/france24_player#

but I can in Chromium!

Do you know what could be the reason?
Thanks in advance!

alessio

Comment: Could the people who are voting this question down please explain why?

Comment: @DylanMcCall The down-votes are probably people who have run out of close votes. We've been [cleaning up](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2863/its-time-for-clean-up-week) and this is an alternate way to remove duplicates/[abandoned](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2813/changes-to-how-we-close-abandoned-questions), etc. I just down-voted this because it is both a dupe and abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have Flash installed in Firefox.

Chrome already has built in Flash support so it does not require you to install anything, in the other hand Firefox relies in an external plugin to open the player on that site.

for more information on how to install Flash in your system please visit [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player) and follow the instructions for your system.

Comment: Now it works.  Just clicking on "Live".