# Will 64 bits flash be available in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, flash

In previous versions I was able to install 64 bit flash from the sevenmachines ppa, it was removed so I thought Ubuntu added it to official repos, but it installs the 32 bit version and the nspluginwrapper.

Any way to install the 64 bit version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is available in the partner repository. Enable partner repository first then you can do:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

Have a look at this:

[How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why flash 32 bits is available in current repos but there is the need of enabling another one for the 64 bits version.