# Adobe Flash Player Installation Fails 

Tags: 11.10, installation, flash

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. The Firefox error message says

"A plugin is needed to display this content:
Adobe Flash Player Installer"

So I install it. Then it says "Installed - restart FireFox" I restart Firefox and the same error message appears.

This problem doesn't happen with Windows 7 (IE, Chrome & Firefox are fine) or my previous version of Ubuntu.  Problem occurs when I access CallOfRoma.com

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 64 bits?

Comment: Can you add how you installed Flash to your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 64 bit O.S., you should try installing this package in Software Center:

[image]

Hope it helps.

- [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

Comment: I have sixty four bits and I'm proud of it! :)

Answer (score -1):

Download the following zip file and extract it

> ftp://www.daba.lv/pub/MultiVide/MacroMedia/x64/install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz

after extracting you will get a file name

> libflashplayer.so

copy the file in

> /usr/lib/firefox/browser/plugins

then restart the firefox

Comment: What is the point of downloading from some site, when this file is available at Adobe site.