# How to downgrade Flash from 11.x to 10.3

Tags: flash, downgrade, gpu

Ubuntu v11.10

Adobe stripped gpu hardware acceleration from flash 11 due to security concerns.  That's great, but I'd like to the accelerated video that Flash 10.3 affords on my nettop.  The problem is, I've looked all over for adobe.com for a legacy version, and there's none to be found.  Is there a way I could uninstall Flash 11 and install version 10.3 with a package installer or something?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You will not get **Adobe Flash 11.3** on Linux as released by Adobe themselves, but if you install Google Chrome it comes pre-packed with **PepperFlash 11.3** and the hardware acceleration does indeed work (for me at least).

If not being open-source concerns you, then you can install Chromium and use the PepperFlash plugin on that also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this site for older flash players: [Archived Adobe Flash Players](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#main_Archived_versions)
Download the required archive and extract it to a folder.
Look for the tar.gz archive for linux in one of the subfolders.
Follow the steps given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184031/58990) for installation.