# Flash update fails and now it doesnt work only youtube videos work

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

Update manager popped up today so i pressed install since i don't bother to question it anymore since its reliable and does what its suppose to do.So yeah it was a Flash update but it fails and now it doesnt work only youtube videos work.I opened up firefox and it pops this message up asking me to install flash and something else which i cant remember the name of it since at this point i thought i was saved but im pretty sure it was some kind of player or something so i press install but that fails too and as a last result i go checkout the software center and it shows that flash is installed to i uninstall it and try again but no luck still have the same problem and yeah since i am a total noob to ubuntu i don't really know whats going on anymore.

I really need help/thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Flash Aid add-on on firefox and follow the wizard instructions.Restart the browser and the problem should probably be fixed. At least that was the solution for me.