# I cannot watch some videos after upgrading to flashplugin

Tags: flash, youtube

After upgrading to flashplugin, I cannot watch videos on the internet.
I also cannot watch some other youtube videos.

I'd say it's a bug in Gnash, any ideas?

Comment: you can report bugs for Gnash in this link http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/bugs.html and about your problem I don't understand are you bugs did from use Gnash only or not you try to use flash player from adobe it's working fine

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/105101/18612

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la solución cuando el problema es que antes de la actualización si que se veían los vídeos, ya que estaba correctamente instalado el plugin Flash Player, pero han dejado de verse tras la actualización.

Ejecutar en la terminal: `gksu gedit /usr/bin/firefox`   con lo que se abre el ejecutable de Firefox con el procesador de textos, con permisos para modificarlo.
Debajo de la primera linea del archivo,donde dice: `#!/bin/sh`
hay que añadir la línea:
`export XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1`  de forma que ésta sea la segunda línea del archivo.
Guardar los cambios en el archivo, cerrarlo, y reiniciar Firefox, y ya se vuelven a ver los vídeos.

Al actualizar Firefox se reescribe la configuración del navegador pero no las opciones de vídeo como por ejemplo las transparencias, lo que hace que el plugin falle al renderizar la imagen. Lo que se hace añadiendo  esta línea es decirle que tenga en cuenta dichas transparencias.

---

*English translation (with the help of Google Translator, plus formatting and clarity changes):*

Here's the solution, when the problem is that the videos worked before the upgrade, but not after.

Run in terminal:

```
gksu gedit /usr/bin/firefox
```

That opens the Firefox executable script with a word processor, with permission to modify it. Below the first line of the file where it says `#!/bin/sh`, you must add the line:

```
export XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1
```

That should be the second line of the file. Save the changes to the file, close it and restart Firefox, and you should be able to re-watch the videos.

Firefox was rewritten to update the browser settings but no video options such as transparency, which makes the plugin fails to render the image. That line, once added, accounts for those transparencies.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Flash Aid add-on on firefox  and follow the wizard instructions.Restart the browser and the problem should  probably be fixed.  At least that was the solution for me.