# How to transfer My Favorites from Windows 

Tags: 11.04

I keep asking how to transfer my favourites from Windows to Ubuntu Bookmarks and no-one seems to be able to tell me in simple language. Videos in web pages don't play it's just a black space. How can I boot Ubuntu as my default page without losing the option to go to Windows.

Comment: You haven't specified what browser you were using on Windows. You haven't specified what browser you are currently using on Ubuntu.

Comment: There are three question in here, you should ask them separately instead (actually you'll find answers to the other two [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/change-the-grub-boot-order-for-ubuntu-11-10)). If those are the questions you wanted to ask, just edit this question to be about bookmarks alone (and don't forget to add your browser on Ubuntu and Windows). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be something like Xmarks
http://www.xmarks.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer your bookmarks from Internet Explorer or something, I don't know any automated way. (But you can import them to FireFox / Chrome first.) If you were using FireFox / Chrome, bookmarks can be synced across different installs, so this has nothing to do with your Operation System.

Flash Video ? If so, install Flash Player. You can find it in the Software Center. (No command line input needed.)

Which kind of Ubuntu install did you use ? If it's Wubi, just press F8 to call the boot list.