# How do I load abobe flash?

Tags: flash, adobe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

I am very new to ubuntu. So far I am happy with it but I need to learn how to download flash. Well, I have downloaded it but I don't know what to do next. Or another opensource program that works. I am running ubuntu 11.04 and firefox. There is much to learn and just need a little direction. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of results if you google for 'install adobe flash ubuntu'.
You downloaded the .deb file, then use Software Center to install it. Or use `sudo dpkg -i path_to_the_flash_deb_file`. Make sure you downloaded the correct version (32bit/64bit) for your OS architect.

Answer (score -1):

The easier way is to install the Ubuntu restricted packages from the Ubuntu software center.

On the software center just search for Ubuntu restricted and you get it directly! You will have Flash, Java and many other "licence restricted" packages in one shot!