# Why I can't see any videos online?

Tags: video, flash

I was using ubuntu 11.04 and everything was ok. Suddenly (after an update, I think) I was unable to see any video (any website) using firefox.
I decided to do a clean, new installation (from CD) of Ubuntu 11.10 and the problem is exactly the same no videos on firefox (no matter website)
I already tried flash-aid with Beta versions and stable versions and nothing.
I'm a pretty new ubuntu (Linux) user.

Any help and/or advice please ????

[image]

[image]

Comment: There was a similar issue only days ago, can't find it right now. It had to do with a recent flash upgrade and the trick was to go back to an older version. Search this site a little and you'll probably come across it quite quickly. I'm off to bed now.

Comment: Can you try this and update your question with what happens? http://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player

Answer (score 3):

Adobe flash player can be download here @ http://get.adobe.com/cn/flashplayer/ .

And when you finish installing, you must restart firefox to see video online. If that does not work, you can go to firefox website to download the newest stable  version Firefox 11.0 at http://www.firefox.com. That may be help to you.

**OR**

You can install chromium web browser to have a try. Open the terminal and input the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: Nothing changed. with chromium say "missing plug-in" in the black square where it suppose to be played the video

Comment: please note that some online videos maybe need Windows media player plugin,not flash. You can just click the 'missing plug-in' to install the missing the plugin. Try again to have a try.

Comment: I already try but nothing. The 'missing plug-in' label it's not a button or link to click on it. It's just a sing letting me know it is not working but clicking on it do nothing. I'm posting two pictures in my original question so you can see.

Comment: SORRY it is not possible to upload pictures to this site

Comment: ok,you can upload images to plublic image website,such as http://imgur.com/ . One picture is worth with thousands of words !

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/sQTRC.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/d0JQi.png

Comment: oh,man. The screenshot seems that you have installed the flash player. It run need your permission. You can reference from http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html. Good Luck !