# AUPEO online radio doesn't work in chromium

Tags: chromium

On the webpage of [AUPEO](https://www.aupeo.com/) online radio is the player visible, and the track it's supposed to play is also visible. But it doesn't start playing. I'm using Chromium in Ubuntu 12.04.

How to solve this?

Comment: Do you have [flash installed](http://askubuntu.com/a/65002/24694)? Does it work on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

If you supply the argument ?use_flash=true it will use the Flash plugin instead of Chromium's HTML5 Audio support:

http://www.aupeo.com/?use_flash=true