# Adobe will stop releasing new versions of Flash - what will happen to flash support in Ubuntu?

Tags: flash

Adobe's Flash [download page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) is displaying a message:

> NOTE: Adobe Flash Player 11.2 will be the last version to target Linux
>   as a supported platform. Adobe will continue to provide security
>   backports to Flash Player 11.2 for Linux.

What is the plans for Flash support in the future?

With a bit of luck HTML5 media support will drop website developer's dependency on Flash.

Comment: not a true answer so I will comment, it may be that Firefox will change their minds about using a **pepper** like API similar to Google's Chrome if they foresee a major loss of Linux market-share if they don't.  This is just speculation on my part, the responses I read from Mozilla when this news first can out doesn't give me much hope however(sorry don't remember where I read it and can't find it now so I can't include a link).  They made it very clear they had **NO** plans to do so

Comment: I just found [THIS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NPAPI:Pepper) page on wiki.mozilla but it is very minimal, I did see a more extensive comment from Mozilla but still cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, basically if we want to keep up with Flash Player future versions and corresponding features and improvements, other than security fixes, we will have to switch to Google Chrome. Adobe went on to say that future updates to Flash Player beyond version 11.2 for Linux will be available only through the Pepper API that will run on Google Chrome and not through a download from Adobe directly. Mozilla hasn't provided any statement about this that I know of so far, so it is expected that Firefox will just use the last version provided by Adobe for the years to come.

I also wish that html5 takes over the Internet, however some functionalities still rely strongly upon Flash player, such as media streams and it will take some time until we get rid of it.

Read [this](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2154741/adobe-googles-pepper-api-future-flash-support-linux) and [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/adobe-adandons-flash-on-linux) for additional details:

There has been some heavy discussion about this as well at Ubuntu Forums. Check those out:
[1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2005367) [2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2035570) [3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2035048)

Comment: great answer, I too wish it could contain better news.....

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it may be the last version usable on Linux; HTML5 will eventually take over anyway. Chromium on the Ubuntu Software Center has a Flash Plugin; that may mean Flash will still work on Chromium, but still will not work in other browsers and you cannot download it directly from Adobe's website.

Hope that helps.