# Adobe PDF for Ubuntu 64 bit 15.10

Tags: adobe-reader

I have upgraded to a 64 bit, and installed Ubuntu 15.10, I'm lacking a good PDF reader.
How do I install Adobe Reader for Ubuntu even though it is no longer available for Linux?

Comment: Aside from that...  I've been using the Foxit PDF reader which is free at this time, and I find it to be pretty good.  I have not yet tried to use it to fill in forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did Adobe stop Flash Player for Linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186779/why-did-adobe-stop-flash-player-for-linux)

Comment: Did you consider Evince?

Comment: What happens when you just install it from the partners repo?

Comment: @DnrDevil Huh? Adobe PDF Reader isn't Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: Here you can get help: http://www.binarytides.com/install-adobe-acrobat-reader-9-5-ubuntu/ We have to download from adobe repository:
ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/

Answer (score 7):

If you are asking how to install Adobe PDF for Ubuntu 64 bit 15.10, then here you go. Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

First, install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libidn11 libpango1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxext6 libxml2 libxt6 zlib1g lsb-release debconf
```

Then, download and install adobe reader:

```
wget http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/acroread/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb
```

Finally, open adobe reader and accept the licence:

```
acroread &
```

Comment: Any tips how to make it work on Ubuntu 14.0.4?

Comment: @Ashu Sure, just follow the instructions. This should work for any version ≥ 13.04.

Comment: I got an error `Errors were encountered while processing: acroread-bin` when executing `dpkg -i` on `ubuntu 14.04`
running this command before fixed is `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: failed for me too - load of dependency problems..

Comment: @bph Hey, if you have dependency problems, try using gdebi to install instead of dpkg as this should automate the process. `sudo apt-get install gdebi; sudo gdebi ./acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb`