# How to use a web page that requires Flash player 11.6?

Tags: flash

I want to visit a web page that requires Flash player 11.6, but I aslo visit the page of download of [Adobe Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/), and they tell us.

> **Note**: Flash Player 11.2 is the last supported Flash Player version for Linux. Adobe will continue to provide security updates.

Does anybody know a way to visit a website with this restrictions?

Comment: Could you please provide link to this website you trying to visit?

Comment: Sure, this one: http://lyricalgame.com/lyrics_editor/

Comment: Read this article for more details - very useful explanation. http://askubuntu.com/questions/172783/adobe-will-stop-releasing-new-versions-of-flash-what-will-happen-to-flash-supp?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Adobe Flash Player about page](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/), release 11.8 is available for Chrome on Linux. You must thus install Chrome and access the [Player Download Centre](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect) with it.

Comment: Great, I will try it.

Comment: For install pepper flash player go into http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html