# Unable to play FIFA videos, StarSports Videos on Firefox 30 (Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit)

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, flash

I am using FF 30 on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed flash and youtube is working fine. However some videos from some sites aren't playing - Foot ball videos (FIFA) and Cricket videos (Starsports) etc. Just black screen appears.

Same videos are working fine on Google chrome

Some links which I couldn't play on Firefox

http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/videos/highlights/match=300186474/index.html

http://www.starsports.com/cricket/tour/tourid=130/matchvideos/vod/videoid=1340276/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is looks like this is to do with the version of Flash - Linux systems [now have to use an old version of Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172783/adobe-will-stop-releasing-new-versions-of-flash-what-will-happen-to-flash-supp).

The short answer is use [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/) - command line instructions for installing it are [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/79284/178596). 
Chrome uses an embedded version of Flash (Pepper Flash), which is still updated to the latest version on all distributions.
You can also use Chromium and the Pepper flash plugin:[image]

Other answers - which are better for Firefox users (like me):

- Use [FreshPlayerPlugin](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/fresh-player-plugin-pepper-flash.html), which borrows the plugin from Google Chrome.
  Instructions for 14.04:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
  ```

  You can then open `about:addons` in Firefox, and enable the plugin under 'Plugins'. It may be easier if you remove the original Flash plugin first, as Firefox seems to prefer using that. It does seem to work (the usual Flash plugin doesn't):

  [image]
- Use [Pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/about.html) (instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html)) which sort of uses Wine to pretend to be a Windows machine.

Comment: I tried freshplayerplugin and videos are playing fine, but the plugin is still not stable and is crashing very often (even in youtube)

Comment: A fairly rubbish solution to that would be to keep the standard Flash plugin installed, and only install the `freshplayerplugin` with `apt` when you need it - its seems fairly difficult to enable one flash version and not the other version in Firefox... I'll look for a workaround

Comment: That is also possible using a deb package file from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freshplayerplugin/) - N.B. You probably want to check whether Firefox + FreshPlayerPlugin are the same *bit (32bit/64bit). Another thing is that you may want to try fiddling with the settings in the [config file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin/master/data/freshwrapper.conf.example) - don't enable hardware acceleration.

Comment: Installing it every time I need, would be too difficult. Even if I do that, since plugin is crashing on these sites as well, my purpose wasnt served.