# Flash player blocked?

Tags: flash

When I go to websites using Flash in Firefox, I get this warning:

> This plugin is vulnerable and it should be updated.

Mozilla's [plugin check](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/) agrees:

> Adobe Flash Player Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202 vulnerable 11.2.202.438

But if I follow the update link and download the Ubuntu version (opening with Software Center) I get

> There isn’t a software package called “adobe-flashplugin” in your current software sources.

If I run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y flashplugin-installer
```

I'm told

> flashplugin-installer is already the newest version.

So how can I update?

Comment: You definitely need to restart the browser. I believe you might have to log out and back in as well. (I had this happen to me on a Fedora install just last night; it didn't see the updated flash until I logged back in. But I'm not sure how the flash update is recognized and whether Ubuntu handles it differently)

Comment: @chaskes: I'm embarassed to say that this was my problem. Would you post this as an answer?

Comment: Don't be embarassed. ;) I won't say how long it took me to try that last night. Answer posted

Comment: The Flashplugin has been updated yesterday. The most recent version is 11.2.202.442 for Linux. Update now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another update: Currently flash may be blocked if it doesn't show as having the right version - e.g. for me on Firefox it shows as 11.2.202.569 in Firefox (And blocks it) but the package has `11.2.202.577` installed (the flash lib binary shows also `11_2_202_577`, so something's broke). Basically it is up to date if it matches the version [here](https://www.adobe.com/uk/software/flash/about/).

---

UPDATE (from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/FirefoxAndAdobeFlashNPAPI):

> Firefox blocks Adobe Flash NPAPI plugin for 11.2.202.481 and earlier
>
> Several serious [security vulnerabilities](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/flash-player/apsb15-18.html) were found in Adobe's flash
>   plugin with exploits known to be in the wild. Because of the critical
>   nature of the vulnerabilities, the Mozilla foundation decided to [block](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-ons-cause-issues-are-on-blocklist?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Add-ons+Blocklist)
>   this version of the [plugin](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1182751). Unfortunately, at the time of the
>   blocklist, only the PPAPI version of the plugin (as used by chromium)
>   was available and Firefox users found the NPAPI plugin was blocked via
>   Firefox's click-through security mechanism.
>
> ***UPDATE:*** As of 2015/07/16, Adobe released 11.2.202.491 which fixes all known issues for PPAPI and NPAPI and updates are available for Ubuntu
>
> Timeline
>
> - 2015 Jul 14: Adobe releases [flash plugin security update for PPAPI](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/flash-player/apsb15-18.html) ahead of NPAPI
> - 2015 Jul 14: Ubuntu Security contacts Adobe regarding NPAPI. Ubuntu told NPAPI plugin will be ready soon
> - 2015 Jul 14: Ubuntu releases adobeflash-plugin and flashplugin-nonfree with updates for PPAPI only
> - 2015 Jul 16: Adobe releases updates for NPAPI (11.2.202.491)
> - 2015 Jul 16: Ubuntu releases adobeflash-plugin and flashplugin-nonfree with updates for NPAPI (11.2.202.491), including
>     the previous PPAPI fixes
>
> <sup>SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/FirefoxAndAdobeFlashNPAPI (last edited
>   2015-07-16 13:36:40 by jdstrand)</sup>

You should be able to update/install it using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

(or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`, `sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin-installer && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` etc)

or, it should also be updated if you use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

Flash is currently being blocked in Firefox by default in all versions:

> [image]

Anyway, [to fix it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-adobe-flash-click-play-firefox):

- Open the Add-ons Manager ('Tools' > 'Add-ons', `about:addons`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Go to Plugins
- In the dropdown next to 'Shockwave Flash' select 'Ask to Active'

***Please only do this if desperate - [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/html5) and other sites now have a option to use HTML5, which should be used in preference to this)***

This is due to the [unfixed security issues in the Adobe Flash plugin](https://grahamcluley.com/2015/07/adobe-flash-zero-day-bugs/), which can be widely exploited by attackers.

The flash plugin in general is very insecure and should be replaced - apparently Adobe and others should be reducing the use of Flash to replace it with HTML5, WebGL and other open standards. One of the reasons *(other than they couldn't be asked...)* that [the Linux version of Flash is stuck at 11.2](https://askubuntu.com/q/172783/178596) *(the version for linux gets security backports for 5 years from release)* is due to the supposed [roadmap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html) with which Adobe will remove Flash support globally (supposedly).

See also:

- [Twitter - Facebook Security Chief's view on the matter](https://twitter.com/alexstamos/status/620306643360706561)
- [The Register - Adobe: You just don't know what it's LIKE having to look after Flash security](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/07/14/adobe_response_to_security_holes/)

Comment: @mchid - i think it is happening on other OSs as well (everyone will just switch to chrome so Google can track everyone's movements...). Also its better flash being blocked and not being hacked i suppose...

Comment: The problem I have is that I can't watch TV now on Firefox as the website thinks I need to update flash and they don't offer support for chrome which gets a generic error and can't play the stream. They used to use silver light which works fine but switched to flash the same day Firefox started the block, maybe just a coincidence.

Comment: @mchid - its not the website that think you need to update flash, its the browser. You either need to the above fix (Firefox currently blocks 'Always Activate' , or do DrTechno's fix (I think Mozilla has classified all current flash versions as unsafe, Adobe will have to do a update fixing the specified problems to sort it out)

Comment: Thanks, I finally got an update for flash on firefox that is not considered unsafe and firefox excepts it but the website still does not. I believe they check for the newest version 18 so it seems to be unrelated to the firefox issue, just the website.  I called the company and they just said they don't support linux (I don't want support, just don't want to be blocked).

Comment: Please update your answer, Wilf, to include the fact there is an update now available which is OK by Firefox.  (Not necessarily the world at large, but Firefox at least)

Comment: After running updates today as per the update in this comment, Firefox still is blocking my Flash, and my version is still showing up as 11.2.202.481 in firefox.  (Clicking on "Update Now" in Firefox just takes me to a screen explaining why the plugin is blocked, no option to update.)

Comment: @SteveKroon - try using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`. Firefox will only unblock if it is a version newer than the 481 release.

Comment: purging and reinstalling fixed the problem after a firefox restart.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer

Comment: `flashplugin-installer is already the newest version.`

Comment: then try sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin-installer then run sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer again

Comment: @TrevorClarke doesn't work. I'm also being blocked by websites that require the "newest" version. Clicking on the link goes to adobe and adobe goes to software center. Newest version already installed reinstalled and re-reinstalled with flashplugin-installer >(

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer` ?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that all versions of adobe flash (current version on all operating systems) is blocked now from automatically running.
what I did is with firefox closed, open up the home foldier, show hidden files then go to .mozilla/firefox/*.default and edit the pluginreg.dat file search for your version (mine was 11.2.202.481 located under the entry  /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so:$ in the file)
I changed the 11 to 19  and no more annoying message from firefox.
now firefox thinks my version is 19.2.202.481

Comment: Why do that? Why manipulate Firefox and probably trick someone else who just needs to use your computer to look something up, where you don't provide them guest access? As Wilf mentioned, you can set it to `Ask to Activate` and it'll work when you need it. Also these plugin updates happen every now and then, which would require to always remember how to fake the version number and remember that you faked it if you use more than one computer with Firefox. Managing plugins through Firefox is the better and more consistent solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained here: https://blocklist.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked/p796
The plugin for Linux is not safe :(

Comment: Usually only old versions are blocked - the flash plugin for every OS is unsafe (the linux one gets the secuirty fixes of the newer versions despite being 11.2)

Comment: This is a bunch of milarkey, that notice is for version 11.2.202.424 or older and I'm running 11.2.202.481. Last I checked, 481 was higher than 424. In fact, I used a calculator  to verify that 481 *is* greater than 424 by 51 (math for the 8 year old elementary students running firefox)!

Answer (score 0):

Shockwave Flash 11.2.202.491 installed in the regular Ubuntu software update on 10/28/2016 is still blocked as far as I can tell.

Comment: The latest version in the Ubuntu archive is `11.2.202.643`, so you can't reasonably have got `11.2.202.491` via a regular software update recently.