# How does Ubuntu control plugins

Tags: upgrade

Blocking Adobe Flash plugin, will not run items on various webpages. Does Adobe Flash support?

Comment: Does Adobe Flash support what?

Comment: Its probably just a Firefox thing: [Flash player blocked?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/579476/flash-player-blocked). Flash has been blocked in Firefox due to security whatevers

Comment: Maybe I asked wrong it says Adobe that it will not support after a certain software level.