# Ubuntu 12.04 And Flash Support

Tags: 12.04, flash

I need flash support to do some of my school work.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.  How do I download flash?
This post says support has ended for [flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172783/adobe-will-stop-releasing-new-versions-of-flash-what-will-happen-to-flash-supp).

Although it does say Google Chrome supports flash, but it won't let me download Google Chrome on Google's website.  Chromium appears to not come with flash.

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin

Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by 
another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: @Chai 64 bit Ubuntu but I can use 32 bit if that makes it easier(I think I can anyways).

Comment: No, Chrome doesn't support 32-bit. Since you have 64-bit, you'll be able to get Chrome.

Comment: That post is obsolete. Please check out [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).

Comment: Check out [these instructions for installing Chrome via the terminal](http://askubuntu.com/a/510186/616451).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex: Just to clarify: Even if Chrome comes with Flash built-in, there is no need to install Chrome only to get Flash working. Please see the link I posted. `adobe-flashplugin` provides Flash for both Firefox & friends and Chromium/Opera/Vivaldi.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I will try that soon but I don't think that will work.  I have tried the official google page and it says my Ubuntu version is outdated.  If there is way to download that last supported version of Ubuntu 12.04 that might work.

Comment: Ahh, then it's probably right. Try Gunnar's method to get it working in non-Chrome browsers.

Comment: Your Ubuntu release is obsolete. It's supported until April and that's it. You should consider installing a supported version and that alone will solve most of your current issues.

Comment: @CelticWarrior my wifi doesn't work on the newer versions for some reason not to mention I can't even boot the live cd on a 2011 Macbook Pro.

Comment: Even if that was true - It really isn't - "End of Life", "unsupported", etc. are still applicable. AskUbuntu does **not** support EoL releases and yours is about to become one. Now do yourself a favor and test 16.04. If something isn't working ask a new question with pertinent hardware specs. Some additional details may be asked later, make sure you edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @CelticWarrior As of right now it doesn't even boot on my hardware.  What version of Ubuntu are you using if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I use a combination of 16.04 LTS for production, 16.10 for some "media players" and the dev branch 17.04 (testing only). You can ask a question about it not booting but I can tell you right now it's not a problem with the newer releases, it's either a problem with the media itself and/or with *how* you're trying to boot it but, again, that's a different question. However, I wonder how you figured out the *wifi doesn't work on the newer versions* if you haven't booted a live session... Aren't you making excuses not to upgrade? Rhetorical question, of course.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have update to 14 but it is glitchy.  The internet took a different method to get to work but is working now.  It failed in the install with I think cups or something like that so I haven't trusted it very much.

Comment: This is not a forum. My original comment had the sole intention of making you aware of the problem, not to engage in chat. If you already have 14.04 why are you asking about 12.04? Either edit your question or deleted it altogether and post another if it must. It's a waste of time otherwise.