# How do I download a flash player?

Tags: flash, video-streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

I only just installed Ubuntu and I'm trying to watch movies and videos online but it won't let me since I don't have the right plugins installed. I tried to download adobe flash player but it won't download.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is go to the Ubuntu Software Center and install the Adobe Flash Player.

Make sure you disable any other plugins in your browser that could be conflicting like lightspark or gnash.

Answer (score 0):

If you find problems with the installation of Adobe Flash for some reason, you can also download the [Google Chrome](http://chrome.google.com) browser, which includes built-in Flash software.