# Package dependencies cannot be resolved: flashplugin 

Tags: apt, flash

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

details:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

flashplugin-installer:
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install -f` and add the output of it to your post.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Here it is:

murat@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
murat@ubuntu:~$

Answer (score 1):

To install the **flashplugin** package on Ubuntu, open up the Ubuntu Software Center, and search for "flash" (without the quotes). After you install it, restart your web browser(s), and Flash should be working!

- [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `aptitude`:

`sudo aptitude install flashplugin-installer`

If you don't have `aptitude` installed on your machine `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.

Hope this helps.